# SetTimeout causing submitted data duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been playing with a toy NoteApp, learning more about JS. Come across a problem I can not seem to figure out. I have a setTimeout to add/remove classes for a little bit of fluff on it, but since adding it duplicates are submitted when adding new notes.

Easier to see when you view the pen: http://codepen.io/jhealey5/pen/KldjC - Works fine on submitting one thing, but after you add another it duplicates.

I'm not sure if it's the time out or the loop, but it happened after adding the timeout so...

Here's the code:

```
var noteApp = {
        init: function() {
            if (this.hasStorage) {
                this.elements().events();
                storedNotes = [];
                storedNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage["notes"]);
                this.showNotes(storedNotes); 
            }
        },
        elements: function() {
            this.input  = $('#input');
            this.submit = $('#submit');
            this.list   = $('#list');
            this.del = $('.del');
            return this; 
        },
        events: function() {
            var self = this;

            this.submit.on('click', function(){
                self.addNote();
                self.init();
            });
            this.del.on({
                click: function(){
                  self.delNote($(this).parent());
                },
                mouseenter: function() {
                $(this).parent().addClass('to-del');
                },
                mouseleave: function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('to-del')
                }
            });
        },
        hasStorage: (function() {
            return typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"; 
        })(),
        addNote: function() {
            var self = this;
            if (this.input.val() === "" || this.input.val() === " " ) {
              this.input.addClass('shake');
              setTimeout(function () {
                  self.input.removeClass('shake');
              }, 500);
              return false;
            } else {
              this.saveNote(this.input.val());
              this.list.append('<li>' + this.input.val() + '<span class="del">×</span></li>');
              this.clearField(); 
            }
        },
        clearField: function() {
          var self = this;
          this.input.addClass('added');
          setTimeout(function () {
            self.input.removeClass('added');
            self.input.val('');
          }, 400);
        },
        delNote : function(note) {
            note.children('span').remove();
            var noteText = note.text();
            for (var i = storedNotes.length; i > -1; i--) {
                if (storedNotes[i] == noteText) {
                  storedNotes.splice(i, 1);
                  localStorage["notes"] = JSON.stringify(storedNotes);
                }
            }
            note.addClass('removing').fadeOut(100, function(){
            $(this).css({
                "visibility":"hidden", 
                'display':'block'
              }).slideUp(100, function(){
                $(this).remove();
                noteApp.checkEmpty();
              });
            });
        },
        saveNote : function(note) { 
            if (storedNotes.length > 0) {
              storedNotes[storedNotes.length] = note;
            } else {
              storedNotes[0] = note; 
            }
            localStorage["notes"] = JSON.stringify(storedNotes); 
            this.checkEmpty();
        },
        showNotes : function() {
            this.list.empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < storedNotes.length; i++) {  
              this.list.append('<li>' + storedNotes[i] + '<span class="del">×</span></li>');
            }
            this.elements().events();
            this.checkEmpty();
        },
        checkEmpty : function() {
          if (!this.list.children('li').length) {
              this.list.addClass('empty');
            } else {
              this.list.removeClass('empty');
            }
        }
    }

    $(function() { 
      noteApp.init();  
    });
```

I'm aware some of that code probably isn't done very well, I'm learning, any additional pointers are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: One more note – `init()` and `showNotes` binds event - one click fires many action as many events listening for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeut` is not a problem. The problem comes from initialization application after each note.

improved events delegation

```
events: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.submit.on('click', function(){
        self.addNote();
    });

    this.list.on('click', '.del', function() {
        self.delNote($(this).parent());
    }).on('mouseenter', '.del', function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('to-del');
    }).on('mouseleave', '.del', function() {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('to-del')
    });

}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wobCj?editors=001

Comment: Ah that fixes it now, thanks! I knew of the different ways to set events, the optional second attribute, but never knew why one would use that over the other, simpler way. Although it fixes it I'm not quite sure why still...

Comment: Actually it still doesn't fix it entirely, it sometimes puts 2 notes in, can't figure out why and when exactly, but it definitely does...

Comment: my bad, missed the commented out call :) thanks again!